# How can I force cutting ZPL command to work on Godex Printer EZ2350i V1.005

Tags: printing, zpl, zpl-ii

I'm trying to use ^MMC,N command to cut material at which printer prints. Printer model is Godex EX2350i V1.005. Everything prints well except cutting. Below I include simple snippnet code:

```
^SZ2^XA^MTT^PON^PW360^LL360^LS0^LT0^PQ1
^FO50,10^BY3^BEN,70,Y,N^FD5900418241574^FS
^FO120,120^A0N,40,35^FWN^FD15^FS
^FO160,160^A0N,59,53^FWN^FD11-12-13^FS
^FO90,220^A0N,35,31^FWN^FDcode^FS
^XZ^MMC
```

Certainly in printer preferences is set cutter mode after each label. I also tried after each task but it doesn't improve at all.

Comment: You might try using the ^CN (cut now, see the manual for params) with the ^MM (using kiosk mode).  If that doesn't work I'd open a case with Godex and let them know their emulation isn't supporting the cut command properly.  Most manufacturers want to know when the emulation isn't working properly.

Comment: I wrote to them and they told me to use ^MMC before ending label command like that:
^MMC^XZ - but it doesn't work. ^CN in connection with kiosk mode doesn't work too.

Comment: How about using the native Godex printer language? I just grabbed a manual and it looks like ^D1 is the command to cut after every label, not sure you could mix and match with ZPL, but if not, you could probably just re-code your label in their language [Manual](http://www.godexintl.com/us/product/type/Download/1085)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm using EZPL and now it works. Thanks.